# Wordpress category listing in a dropdown list

Tags: wordpress

How to display only main categories in a dropdown list in wordpress.I would like to hide subcategories and need to show all main categories if it has no posts.Following script I tried, but it displaying all categories(main and subcategories).

```
<?php 
// display categories in drop down list
$args = array('hide_empty'=>0,'depth'=>1); 
wp_dropdown_categories($args);
?>
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation for `wp_dropdown_categories`, the depth argument is ignored unless 'hierarchical' is set to true.  Add this argument and you should get the results you are looking for.

```
$args = array('hide_empty'=>0,'depth'=>1,'hierarchical'=> 1, );
wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

Good Luck.